# Hl7 difference visit number, account number, encounter number

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

I am having trouble decipher the differences between key concepts in hl7.

Would someone be kind enough to explain the differences in what the following are:

What is a visit? 
Where is the visit number typically located?
What is an encounter number ? 
Where is the encounter number typically located?
what is the difference between encounter level and visit level in hl7?
What is the account number?

Comment: Answer-seekers beware, the as of 4/25/17 accepted answer is not correct! Please see all comments to all answers below.

Comment: @this - I've edited my answer to state "often". However, please show some real examples where my answer is not the case. Otherwise you're stating that my answer is "wrong" because of semantics, and not actually what occurs in real life - which is that they are all used interchangably.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Patient Account Number/Visit Number/Encounter Number** - These are all *often* the same thing, they're just used interchangeably between different systems and organizations. The visit number is the unique identifier assigned by the healthcare facility(hospital, clinic, surgical center, etc.) that's given to a patient for that one particular visit to the facility.

*The patient account number is located in PID.18 in an HL7 message.*

**Medical Record Number** - The medical record number is the unique identifier given to a patient's medical record that covers all the encounters/visits of the patient within a facility - it's a living history of everything that has happened to the patient with regards to the healthcare facility he is visiting.

*The medical record number is located in PID.3 in an HL7 message.* - Edited.

To explain this, **I'll give an example**:

Little Timmy decided one day that he was going to jump off the roof of his mother's car because, well he's a child.  As Timmy landed on the ground, he stumbled, hit the concrete pavement of the driveway, and broke his little arm.

As Timmy laid there crying, his mother ran out and immediately knew something was serious.  So she rushed Little Timmy with his little broken arm to their local community hospital.  Little Timmy had been there before, last year when he decided to jump off the roof of his house and break his ankle.

When Little Timmy and his mother gets to the hospital, they immediately head for the Emergency Room.  An admit nurse pulls up Little Timmy's Medical Record Number, since he had been to the hospital a year earlier, and sees that the hospital already has a Medical Record on Little Timmy.  Since he already has a Medical Record, there's less paperwork that he needs to do and therefore the admit nurse can admit Little Timmy - When she admits Little Timmy, a unique identifier for this particular visit (the visit number) is attached to Little Timmy's Medical Record Number so that they can document his stay in the hospital until he is discharged with a healing broken arm.

Since Little Timmy had a previous Medical Record, medical staff can go back and look at Timmy's last surgery and encounter with a broken bone and make decisions based on the present and past history.  Little Timmy's medical record holds that history, with the visit of him coming to the hospital for his broken ankle from last year.  This visit last year was also assigned a visit number, and was attached to his medical record number.

By having a visit number attached to each "visit" of the hospital that Timmy has undertaken, they can review past data to see if there are any chronic problems (Timmy likes to jump off of high places), and to assess if additional medical treatment or cautions should be taken.

Please feel free to ask me any questions if this confuses you.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your response.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your response. Would you take a look at the article and provide feedback. http://www.j4jayant.com/articles/hl7/15-hl7-identifiers

Comment: This (as of 4/25/17 accepted) answer is wrong. [GrnMtnBuckeye's  answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29501756/688182) is correct: account number is different from visit/encounter. Definition and location information of visit number can be found here: [PV1.19](https://ushik.ahrq.gov/ViewItemDetails?&system=mdr&itemKey=77543000&enableAsynchronousLoading=true) and that of account number here: [PID.18](https://ushik.ahrq.gov/ViewItemDetails?system=mdr&itemKey=77135000).

Comment: cloyd800 : Please correct your answer because your answer is "accepted" and when we see this post, we first don't know this sentence is wrong : "These are all the same thing, they're just used interchangeably between different systems and organizations.". Thank you @this, your very usefull comment saved my day.

Comment: @Elo - I've edited my answer - however, I've been working with healthcare systems for over a decade and I've never seen a system in the wild that doesn't consider these all the same thing. Please show examples of this. Otherwise, I'll keep my answer as "often".

Comment: @this your comment is right, but SQLSavant is right for older versions

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. After reading more, I found that a Patient ID (MRN) would be in PID3, Account/Patient Account is PID18, and Visit is PID19, so as you said Account/Visit are often the same, but they are different concepts in the spec so they are not 100% interchangeable

Answer (score 5):

An MRN is constant for one patient to represent them from a clinical data perspective for their entire life for an individual hospital.

Visit and Encounter are interchangeable and meant to represent a single visit to the hospital, also known as an episode of care.  This is often used for tracking the care from a clinical perspective: chief complaint of symptoms, presenting diagnosis, testing and procedures performed, clinical documentation, discharge status and diagnosis.

Account number is typically associated with billing and may or may not be the same number as the MRN or the Visit/Encounter, depending on the individual hospital.  An account number could be constant for a patient or gaurantor (person who is overall responsible for payment) or a new one may be generated for each episode, similar to a visit number, but frequently aggregates multiple related Visits/Encounters in to one account number for billing purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Too many people (IT editors) are acting like explanations of @cloyd800 by using PID-18 and PV1-19 the same way, and considering PID-18 contains visit number. Even if it is "often" the case, we must handle all specific cases to respect the HL7 norm.